# Call view modifying function on child view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view which has a function `fadeInOut()` that fades a square in and out.

```swift
struct FadingSquare: View {
    
    @State var fading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .opacity(fading ? 1 : 0)
            .onAppear {
                fadeInOut()
            }
    }
 
    func fadeInOut() {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
            self.fading = true
        }
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1).delay(1)) {
            self.fading = false
        }
    }
    
}
```

That works fine, the square fades in, then fades out.

But I want to place `FadingSquare` in other places, and call `fadingSquare.fadeInOut()` from a parent view. This is what I have attempted:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var fadingSquare = FadingSquare()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            fadingSquare
            Button {
                fadingSquare.fadeInOut()
            } label: {
                Text("Fade")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This does not work, and making `fadingSquare` a `@State` doesn't work either. I'd rather not use `Binding`s, I want the `FadingSquare` to be responsible for its own values.

Comment: You shouldn't ever hold a reference to a view like this or try to reach into a child view from the parent. You need to hold state up at a higher level and pass it down -- you'll have to get over the requirement to store that state in the child view unless you want to do something really convoluted with notifications or something like that.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. Sorry. Yeah @jnpdx is right.

Answer (score 0):

So in SwiftUI, parents can modify their children in really just two ways.

1. Within the parent view, (ContentView) add a `@State` variable to track the fade. Within the child view, (FadingSquare) change the `@State` variable to `@Binding` and remove the default value. Now, within `ContentView`, you can have the square update when the parent's fade variable changes by writing it in the body as `FadingSquare(fading: $ourFadingState)` where `ourFadingState` is that `@State` variable we created.
2. The parent and the child each hold a reference to the same `ObservableObject`. This is the most performant way to do it when dealing with complex UIs. Within the parent's button action, you'd modify the object's fading property. Within the FadingSquare, you'd have an `@ObservedObject` variable which would cause the square to update itself upon any changes, regardless of if they were made within the view itself, a parent, or on the moon.

By the way, for SwiftUI to work properly, you don't keep a fadingView property, you instantiate a brand new one within the body code. This is because when it's a property, it can't update until the parent gets trashed, which will never happen because ContentView is typically the root view of a scene and will never get destroyed. Look at the system SwiftUI views and notice you don't need to hold them within variables either. We do it the same way.

So instead of:

```swift
var fadingSquare = FadingSquare()

var body: some View {
    fadingSquare
}
```

It should be:

```swift
var body: some View {
    FadingSquare()
}
```

Remember that unlike UIKit, a SwiftUI view struct is **not the view itself**. It is a collection of data *describing to the system what the view should contain during a given refresh*, like HTML. So initializing a new `FadingSquare()` within body code is correct and *it will be the same view*, even if it is "a new" struct in code.